# Django Serializer for image array slows things down

Tags: python, django, serialization

I am currently making a Django app that recieves a POST request containing byte array that, given a width and height, is turned into a 2d numpy array.

We are using the Django Rest Framework.

I have changed the names of my classes when posting here on Stackoverflow, everything compiles and runs ok, this is a timing issue.

Normally it takes 0.02s to parse the incoming request when measured using timer.

```
class APIViewEndPoint(APIView):
    def post(self, request):
        params = json.loads(request.body.decode('utf-8'))
        array = params.get("array")
        height = params.get("height")
        width = params.get("width")
        image = np.array(array, dtype=np.uint8).reshape(height, width)
```

This is the serializer which is a much nicer pattern for handling incoming requests.

```
class PostRequestSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    width = serializers.IntegerField(required=True)
    height = serializers.IntegerField(required=True)
    array = serializers.ListField(required=True)
```

Now, we use the serializer and the time takes 0.8s when measured using timer.

```
class APIViewEndPoint(APIView):
    def post(self, request):
        params = json.loads(request.body.decode('utf-8'))
        serializer = PostRequestSerializer(data=params)
        if(serializer.is_valid()):
            data = serializer.data
            image = np.array(data["array"], dtype=np.uint8).reshape((data["height"], data["width"]))
```

Is there a faster way to serialize an array in Django? Ideally, it'd be great if the serializer could also handle the reshaping of the incoming array.

Are there any thoughts on this?

Comment: Are you using djangorestframework?

Comment: Yes. I am using the Django Rest Framework.

Comment: I wonder if `params = request.data` is the same as `params = json.loads(request.body.decode('utf-8'))`?

Comment: What is `LongitudinalSerializer` look like?

Comment: Sorry. PostRequestSerializer is the serializer. I have tried to anonymise the classes used as requested by the project owner. I have edited it.